# Android Nutiteq Map geting marker id

Tags: onclick, android-mapview, marker, nutiteq

I'm developing a map application using nutiteq mapview. I added multiple markers on my map and every marker has a click action. I handle marker click in 'onVectorElementClicked' function but   it doesn't give me my clicked marker's id, only gives to me marker's label title.

```
((DefaultLabel) vectorElement.getLabel()).getTitle()
```

Is there any marker index handle function?

I SOLVED:

When i add marker with for loop, i can set data to marker. This is last parameter of **adsMarker** . As you can see below the code, i can set my for loop's index in a created marker of parameter. So in 'onVectorElementClicked', i can call it using *vectorElement.userData*

```
for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){

            markersLocations = mapLayer.getProjection().fromWgs84(list.get(i).y,list.get(i).x);
            Marker adsMarkers = new Marker(markersLocations, markerLabel, markerStyle_, i);
            advMarkersLayers.add(adsMarkers);
            BasarTrafik.getInstance().setAdsMarker(adsMarkers);

        }
```

Comment: I rephreased your answer as answer to the question. Please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add marker with for loop, i can set data to marker. This is last parameter of Marker constructor. As you can see below the code, i can set my for loop's index in a created marker of parameter. So in 'onVectorElementClicked', i can call it using vectorElement.userData

```
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){

        markersLocations = mapLayer.getProjection().fromWgs84(list.get(i).y,list.get(i).x);
        Marker adsMarkers = new Marker(markersLocations, markerLabel, markerStyle_, i);
        advMarkersLayers.add(adsMarkers);
        BasarTrafik.getInstance().setAdsMarker(adsMarkers);

    }
```